# Or operator not operating as it should ? c++

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

I simply don't understand what the error is. As soon as I make the `if` statement include the `or` operator, my program won't accept any input as correct. It will instead keep outputting wrong even if I input `y` or `n`.

(also sorry if this is rather simple, I'm new to programming)

I attempted to use an `else if`, but it still does not work for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    char ans;
    bool correct = true;
    
    while(correct){
        cout << "Do you like ice cream? (y/n) ";
        cin >> ans;

        if(ans != 'y' || ans != 'n')
        {
            cout << "wrong\n";
        }
        else
        {
            correct = false;
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Thanks for your input!" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(ans != 'y' || ans != 'n')` is always true regardless of what value `ans` is. if ans is `y` its not equal to `n`. If `ans` is  `n` its not equal to `y` if it's any other character its not equal to both `n` and `y`

Comment: Think about it. Explain it to someone else. It helps

Comment: If you're new to programming and you're asking whether the boolean operators in a 25-year-old systems programming language are broken, you're obviously asking the wrong question. Try writing out a truth table, they're really helpful.

Comment: You need to use `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or): `if(ans != 'y' && ans != 'n')` (ie, if `ans` is not `y` **AND** `ans` if not `n` then `wrong`). Also, your `correct` variable doesn't really make sense, and should be removed. Just use a `do..while(true)` loop, and `break` it when ready.

Comment: Thank you guys very much , my logic was flawed and you guys helped my figure that out !  my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ans != 'y' || ans != 'n')
```

This always evaluates to True. You should use && in this scenario instead of ||.

Try to simulate in your mind:

ans = 'n' will evaluate the first part to True

ans = 'y' will evaluate the second part to True

ans = 'potato' will evaluate both parts to True